# Python Selenium click on element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I can locate the XPATH of the element that I want, however it will not allow me to click on it.  In specific, it throws a "WebDriverException."

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
url='https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32261'
browser.get(url)
click=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='next page']")
print(click.get_attribute('title'))
click.click()
```

Returns the following error:
[image]

Comment: It would seem that utilizing "send_keys('next page') prior to the "click.click()" is working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, the XPath was there, however I don't believe I was actually pointed to it when trying the initial "click.click()."  There might be a better solution, however this seems to be working for now.

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   browser=webdriver.Chrome()
   url='https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32261'
   browser.get(url)
   click=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='next page']")
   print(click.get_attribute('title'))
   click.send_keys('next page')
   click.click()
```

Comment: `click.send_keys('next page')` is just a sensless workaround which doesn't really solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You cannot click on required element because it's not visible currently. You should scroll down to "Next" button before clicking it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32261'
browser.get(url)
next_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='next page']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)
next_button.click()
```

Comment: Hi Andersson, if you dont mind the ask, is the execute_script react like the send_keys?  I will try to see if I can incorporate the execute_script in other scrapes as well.  I appreciate the answer!

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure I correctly understood you. `send_keys()` intend to enter characters to input fields or execute keys combinations, e.g. Ctrl+t, etc... `execute_script()` allows you to execute JavaScript code directly from your Python code